# How to correctly reference and set up \label for a custom float

Tags: captions, newfloat

I am using the `caption`, `float` and `newfloat` package in my thesis. I have defined a custom float as follows:

```
floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{model}{thp}{lob}
```

Now I want to reference a label to my model. I placed the `\label` command after `\caption` as I was taught but the references to my customfloat `{model}` still end up as quastion marks. What am I missing here?
Code:

```
\newcommand{\Vertices}{V}
\newcommand{\VerticesDepot}{V_{0}}
\newcommand{\OrderSet}{\Omega}
\newcommand{\order}{\omega}
\newcommand{\agvArc}{x}
\newcommand{\pickerArc}{p}
\newcommand{\Horizon}{T}
\newcommand{\agvFlow}{f}
\newcommand{\pickerFlow}{fp}
    \begin{document}
\frontmatter
\titlepage{}
%
\mainmatter
Example text \ref{model:M2} to reference to model M2.
\chapter{Modelchapter}
\begin{model}[htb] \caption*{M\textsubscript{2}:} \label{model:M2}
\begin{align}
&\textnormal{Minimize} ~ t^* \label{eq:obj15}\\
\intertext{subject to}
\sum_{i \in \VerticesDepot} \agvArc_{ij} \quad &= \quad 1 & & \forall \; j \in \Vertices^{\omega}, \; \omega \in \OrderSet & \label{eq:MIP16}\\
# more and more equations
\end{align}
\end{model}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Why do you use `\caption*` rather than `\caption`?

Comment: @Mico Thanks! I use the \caption* variation because I don't want a numbered caption in front of my Models name (which is M_{number}). If I could define a custom caption that looks exactly like that I would prefer to use \caption but as it is I want to omit the custom float name "model" in the caption.

Comment: I suppose you could run `\refstepcounter{model}\caption*{M\textsubscript{2}}` to suppress the "Model" Prefix. The trouble is that your readers will get confused to no end (and quickly become annoyed by the fact) that cross-reference points to "model 1" but there's no model numbered "1". Is it really that burdensome to show "Model 1" to your readers?

Comment: I guess I can talk to my supervisor and suggest the same thing. Thanks for your help!
The \refstepcounter{model} hint is also greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thesis advisers and Other supervisors really ought to get out of the business of making quirky (and frequently poorly-conceived!) formatting requirements, shouldn’t they?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must confess that I don't understand your use of `\caption*`, as it would appear to defeat the purpose of using LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` mechanism for creating cross-references.

I've simplified your code to what I believe is the bare minimum, while loading the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages to create a highly-visible cross-reference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{float,caption}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{model}{tbhp}{lom}
\floatname{model}{Model}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{model}{model}{models}

\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{chapter} % note the use of '\refstepcounter'

\begin{model}
\caption*{M\textsubscript{2}} \label{mod:M2}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{model}

As shown in \cref{mod:M2}, \dots
\end{document}
```

---

Observe that if I changed `\caption{M\textsubscript{2}}` to `\caption*{M\textsubscript{2}}`, I'd get the following result:

[image]

You might ask, why does the cross-reference say "chapter 1" instead of "model 1"? LaTeX's `\label` mechanism works by looking for the counter variable that was *most recently incremented* via a `\refstepcounter` directive. Since `\caption*` creates an unnumbered caption, the `model` counter variable is *not* incremented; therefore, the `\label` statement latches on to the `chapter` counter variable, since that's the counter variable that was most recently incremented by `\refstepcounter`. (Aside: If I commented out the `\refstepcounter{chapter}` directive, the cross-reference produced by `\cref{mod:M2}` would be doomed to fail since `\label` has nothing to latch on to.)